How to give the position of a player who is somewhere in another script?
I’ve been struggling for a while to figure out how to properly provide other scripts on different objects with the player’s position. Right now, I need to give the player’s position so that a script can place a sound behind them, and I don’t know how to do it.
Please help me approach the solution with the right approach: OOP, SOLID, and so on.
Here is the script that should place the sound behind the player:
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaceSoundBehindPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SoundPositionGenerator soundPositionGenerator;

    [SerializeField] float spawnDistance = 10f;

    public void PlaceBehind(Transform newPosition)
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = newPosition.position;

        transform.position = soundPositionGenerator.NewSpawnApproachinSoundPosition(**playerTransform**, spawnDistance);
    }
}

I had ideas about using events: the player triggers an event about themselves in Start, and other scripts simply remember the player instance by subscribing to the event. This method doesn’t seem reliable because sometimes calls and subscriptions get mixed up. I tried passing the player from one script to the parameters of a public method of another script. But it seems to me that this is not the right way to do it due to violations of OOP and other principles.

Seems logical to set the playerTransform as a public field of this script.

Is this called once or should this rather update continuously?

In general you should have some sort of dependency management.. whether that's serialized fields or injection is opinions and preferences
